# why showing Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\TEST\ajax.php on line 21

Tags: php

## why showing like this ="Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\TEST\ajax.php on line 21"

```
require_once 'includes/db_con.php';
$response = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gre WHERE `verbal-1` = 1");
     $i = 1;
     $unanswer = 0;
     $right_answer=0;
     $wrong_answer=0;

     /*?>$unanswered=0;<?php */
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($response)){ 
     $get_ans = $result['ans1'] + $result['ans2'] + $result['ans3'];

     if(isset($_POST["single-1".$i])){
        if($get_ans == $_POST["single-1".$i]){
        $right_answer++;
        }
     }else if(isset($_POST["double-1".$i],$_POST["double-2".$i])){
        if($get_ans == $_POST["double-1".$i]+$_POST["double-2".$i]){
        $right_answer++;
        }
     }else if(isset($_POST["three-1".$i],$_POST["three-2".$i],$_POST["three-3".$i]){
        if($get_ans == $_POST["three-1".$i]+$_POST["three-2".$i]+$_POST["three-3".$i]){
        $right_answer++;
        }
     }else if(isset($_POST["multi-1".$i],$_POST["multi-1".$i]){
        if($get_ans == $_POST["multi-1".$i]+$_POST["multi-1".$i]){
        $right_answer++;
        }
     }else if(isset($_POST["body-1".$i]){
        if($get_ans == $_POST["body-1".$i]){
        $right_answer++;
        }
     }else{
        $wrong_answer++;
     }
     $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing one ")", It should be else if(isset()).

Answer (score 1):

```
else if(isset($_POST["three-1".$i],$_POST["three-2".$i],$_POST["three-3".$i]){
        if($get_ans == $_POST["three-1".$i]+$_POST["three-2".$i]+$_POST["three-3".$i]){
        $right_answer++;
        }
     }else if(isset($_POST["multi-1".$i],$_POST["multi-1".$i]){
        if($get_ans == $_POST["multi-1".$i]+$_POST["multi-1".$i]){
        $right_answer++;
        }
     }else if(isset($_POST["body-1".$i]){
```

should be

```
else if(isset($_POST["three-1".$i],$_POST["three-2".$i],$_POST["three-3".$i])){
                                                                             ^ - missing 
        if($get_ans == $_POST["three-1".$i]+$_POST["three-2".$i]+$_POST["three-3".$i]){
        $right_answer++;
        }
     }else if(isset($_POST["multi-1".$i],$_POST["multi-1".$i])) {
                                                              ^ - missing
        if($get_ans == $_POST["multi-1".$i]+$_POST["multi-1".$i]){
        $right_answer++;
        }
     }else if(isset($_POST["body-1".$i])) {
                                        ^ - missing
```